# Как узнать локальный адрес при коннекте сокета к удаленному адресу?

Tags: c++, c, сокет

Как узнать локальный адрес при коннекте сокета к удаленному адресу?

К примеру на java делается так:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket("example.com", 80);
        System.out.println(socket.getLocalAddress());
    }
```

Вывод(например):
`/192.168.8.10`

Как получить такой же вывод, но только при написании программы на c.
Дайте короткий пример программы на c, если можно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как узнать локальный адрес при коннекте сокета к удаленному адресу?

Строго говоря, в Си нет собственного сетевого API, но для де-факто стандартных BSD-сокетов есть функция [`getsockname()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getsockname.html):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int rc;

  if(argc!=2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <host>", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  char *hostname = argv[1];

  // DNS запрос
  struct hostent *ent = gethostbyname(hostname);
  if (!ent) {
    fprintf(stderr, "gethostbyname failed: %s\n", hstrerror(h_errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (ent->h_addrtype != AF_INET) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The remote host haven't returned an ipv4 address\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Создание сокета
  int sockfd = socket(ent->h_addrtype, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sockfd<0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Соединение с удалённым хостом
  struct sockaddr_in raddr = {
      .sin_family=AF_INET,
      .sin_port = htons(80),
      .sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)ent->h_addr_list[0]};
  rc = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&raddr, sizeof(raddr));
  if(rc<0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "connect() failed: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Запрос локального адреса к которому привязан сокет
  struct sockaddr_in laddr;
  socklen_t laddr_len = sizeof(laddr);
  rc = getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&laddr, &laddr_len);
  if(rc<0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getsockname() failed: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (laddr.sin_family != AF_INET) { // Не должно случаться в данном примере, но, вообще говоря, полезная проверка
    fprintf(stderr, "socket is binded to non-ipv4 address\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 
  assert (laddr_len <= sizeof(laddr));

  // Печать адреса
  char laddr_sbuf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  const char *laddr_p = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &laddr.sin_addr, laddr_sbuf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  assert(laddr_p);

  printf("%s\n", laddr_sbuf);
}
```

---

```
$ ./a.out stackoverflow.com
192.168.4.9
```

---

Примечания:

- Linux man pages говорит, что [`gethostbyname()`](http://ru.manpages.org/gethostbyname/3) устарела (*obsolete*) и советует вместо неё использовать [`getaddrinfo()`](http://ru.manpages.org/getaddrinfo/3)